# How to split a line stored in a file into strings(bash)

Tags: bash, mutt

I have a file of the format

```
email1 "subject of email1" "body of email1"
email2 "subject of email2" "body of email2"
```

I want to send emails to all the email ids, with subject and body picked from this file.

I have tried something like the following, but didn't work as expected

```
cat ~/file.txt \
| while read -a CONTACT
    do 
       echo ${CONTACT[2]} | mutt -s ${CONTACT[1]} ${CONTACT[0]}
    done
```

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Where are the contacts coming from? It appears you're reading them in from your file.

Comment: @DavidW. CONTACT is coming from 'read -a' over ~/file.txt

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
while read line;do
  eval "set -- $line"
  echo "$3"|mutt -s "$2" "$1"
done <~/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no other double quotes:

```
input="file.txt"

IFS='"'
while read -a CONTACT ; do
  echo -e "<${CONTACT[0]}> <${CONTACT[1]}> <${CONTACT[3]}>"
done < "$input"
```

Output

```
<email1 > <subject of email1> <body of email1>
<email2 > <subject of email2> <body of email2>
```